# Read Excel files from subfolders

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I dont know where I have gone wrong. I have excel files stored in sub-folders which are country names. Now I have written code to find those excels,  read them then extract data from sheets. I have a feeling the code looks good but when I run it, I get empty dataframe. Here is the code :

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os

# Define the parent folder path with double backslashes
parent_folder = '..../data/Pilot_data/'

# Create empty dataframes for each sheet
merged_allowances_df = pd.DataFrame()
merged_allowances_convert_df = pd.DataFrame()
merged_basic_salaries_df = pd.DataFrame()
merged_basic_salaries_convert_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through sub-folders for each country
for country_folder in os.listdir(parent_folder):
    country_folder_path = os.path.join(parent_folder, country_folder)

    if os.path.isdir(country_folder_path):
        # Find all Excel files in the current country folder
        excel_files = [file for file in os.listdir(country_folder_path) if file.endswith('.xlsx')]

        # Loop through Excel files in the current country folder
        for excel_file in excel_files:
            excel_file_path = os.path.join(country_folder_path, excel_file)
            print(excel_file_path)

            # Read Excel data
            if 'Allowances' in excel_file:
                try:
                    allowances_df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, 'Allowances', header=None, skiprows=1)
                    # Process allowances_df as needed
                    merged_allowances_df = merged_allowances_df.append(allowances_df, ignore_index=True)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error reading 'Allowances' sheet in {excel_file}: {str(e)}")


# Now you have separate merged dataframes for each sheet
print("Merged Allowances DataFrame:")
print(merged_allowances_df.head())
```

When I try to print file paths, they look like this

```
..../data/Pilot_data/Angola\DB_Salary_Study_2021_Angola.xlsx
..../data/Pilot_data/Angola\DB_Salary_Study_2021_Angola.xlsx
```

Where an I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Example using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) recursive glob:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


merged_allowances_df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(io=file, sheet_name="Allowances", header=None, skiprows=1) for file in
                                  Path("..../data/Pilot_data/").rglob("*.xlsx") if "Allowances" in file.name])
print(merged_allowances_df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

You've built a lot using os, but could you use glob with recursive set on?

```
file_list = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Windows\\Documents\\projects\\**\*.csv', recursive=True)
```

glob offers quite a range of pattern matching that could be of use. The double ** will allow glob to go down multiple levels of subdirectories, not just one.
For example: [https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-glob-usage/#:~:text=The%20root_dir%20argument%20in%20glob,actual%20current%20directory%20remains%20unchanged](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-glob-usage/#:%7E:text=The%20root_dir%20argument%20in%20glob,actual%20current%20directory%20remains%20unchanged).